# Initializing a fragment, but not showing it immediately

Tags: android

Is there a way to initialize a Fragment fully, without showing it immediately?

I have a WebView in a Fragment, but I don't want to show the Fragment until the WebView is done loading a URL.  However, it seems like I'm not actually able to initialize the Fragment without displaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `Object` of your `Fragment` and do Operations on it , 
if you do not put it on the stage with the `FragmentManager`.

I would recommend you to start loading the Content of the URL in a function, independent of the UI.(NOT `onCreateView`)

Answer (score 0):

as workaround you can call `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` before returning your View inside `onCreateView`.